Got "expected type specifier" error while instantiating my property
My goal is to create nullable value which takes both a default value function and a key to retrieve a potential customization of the value from the flash storage.
But trying to instantiate it as a property member I get "expected type specifier" compile error for the two arguments.
How to fix this?
Here how I use my constructor in my class:
class BatteryConfig {
    static float _defaultPackL1Undervoltage();

    FloatStorageNullableWithDefault packL1Undervoltage("PackL1UndervoltageKey", _defaultPackL1Undervoltage); // <<<== the errors here
};

Here is my base classes:
template <typename T>
class Nullable {
public:
    Nullable() : hasValue_(false) {}
    Nullable(const T& value) : hasValue_(true), value_(value) {}

    bool hasValue() const { return hasValue_; }

    virtual T get() const {
        if (!hasValue_) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Nullable value is not set");
        }
        return value_;
    }

    virtual void set(const T& value) {
        hasValue_ = true;
        value_ = value;
    }

protected:
    bool hasValue_;
    T value_;
};

template <typename T>
class NullableWithDefault : public Nullable<T> {
public:
    NullableWithDefault(const std::function<T()>& defaultValue) : Nullable<T>(), defaultValue_(defaultValue) {}

    T get() const override {
        if (!Nullable<T>::hasValue_) {
            return defaultValue_();
        }
        return Nullable<T>::get();
    }

protected:
    std::function<T()> defaultValue_;
};


class FloatStorageNullableWithDefault : public NullableWithDefault<float> {
public:
    FloatStorageNullableWithDefault(
        const std::string& key,
        const std::function<float()>& defaultValue
    ) : NullableWithDefault<float>(defaultValue), key_(key) {}

    /// returns the key
    std::string getKey() const { return key_; }

private:
    const std::string key_;
};

